# Symfony3 I have to show from a related entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a question.

I have 2 entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="call_center")
 */
class Call {

    /**
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Number", mappedBy="number")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
      private $value;
......
    getters setters

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="number")
 */
class Number {

    /**
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * 
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Call", inversedBy="number")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $link;
```

And I would like to show my data in controller. 
This is my controller

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/pl/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Call')->findAll();

        foreach ($em as $name) {
        switch(1) {
            case $name->getNumber():
                echo $name->getValue();
                echo $name->getLink(); <----PROBLEME
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        }

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'em' => $name
        ));
    }
}
```

Data with entity call displayed but I don't know how dipsplay data from Number (getLink()). The problem is that I have a loop in which I have to display for a particular value relationship. Probably I have to create repository for entity?

```
Entity Call
/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set number
 *
 * @param string $number
 *
 * @return Call
 */
public function setNumber($number)
{
    $this->number = $number;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get number
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNumber()
{
    return $this->number;
}

/**
 * Set value
 *
 * @param string $value
 *
 * @return Call
 */
public function setValue($value)
{
    $this->value = $value;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get value
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getValue()
{
    return $this->value;
}

entity Number

/**
     * Set number
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Call $number
     *
     * @return Number
     */
    public function setNumber(\AppBundle\Entity\Call $number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get number
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Call
     */
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set link
     *
     * @param string $link
     *
     * @return Number
     */
    public function setLink($link)
    {
        $this->link = $link;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get link
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLink()
    {
        return $this->link;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have a string because you tell doctrine to put a string ?

remove the following annotation from your relation :

```
@ORM\Column(type="string")
```

Comment: did it fix your problem ?

Comment: i am not the OP ,  i was trying to help him :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to access it via   `$name->getNumber()->getLink()`  ?

as pointed out below, by tny,   you should fix your annotations, or the above will not work, as getNumber() is currently returning a string instead of a Number instance

Comment: Yes, but I have error Call to a member function getLink() on string

Comment: very strange, according to your entity '->getNumber()' should return a Number instance..    not a string,   can you post your getter, can you also var_dump($name)

Comment: I actualisation my post and adding getters and setters now.

Comment: first of all,   i woud get rid of some confusion, by renaming the number PROPERTY, on the number ENTITY,  to 'call'   instead of 'number' (and setCall and getCall),   it references the Call entity, so just name it, 'call'

Comment: second,   i believe somewhere in you code, you are doing an incorrect setNumber()   using a string instead of an anstance of Number entity, change your setNumber in call,  to allow only instances of 'Number' entity, and try to find where you are incorrectly setting it to a string

Comment: read what tny wrote below ;)    no wonder it is returning a string :)